# .NET 8: Blazor Component losing property value

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I am migrating my code from Blazor Server Side (.NET Core 7) to the new Blazor Web Application (.NET Core 8) and am running into issues with my reusable components.

Inside these components I am doing a call to my API and then fill in a property based on the response. This value is lost when the component is rendered (and yes I made sure the API is returning by debugging).  Meanwhile if I do a direct assignment to the variable then this is kept and rendered. This used to work correctly on the .NET Core 7 version.

```
@using RoboWars.FrontEnd.UI.BlazorV2.Data.Robots.Avatars

@inject AvatarService AvatarService

<h3>MiniCounterComponent</h3>

<p>Current Parameter Value = @CounterValue</p>

<p>Do Minus Stuff = @DOMinusStuff</p>
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ImageURL))
{
    <p>No image mate :S</p>
}else
{
    <p>Image URL = @ImageURL</p>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int CounterValue { get; set; }

    public int DOMinusStuff { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        DOMinusStuff = CounterValue - 10;
        ImageURL = "empty";

        var result = await AvatarService.GetRobotAvatarDetails("44822cb0-fcf0-4e29-b2c9-1ecb133e461a");
        ImageURL = result.URL;
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

[image: Debug value of the api result]

[image: output image]

I tried the different rendering modes inside the component but still have not managed to create the result I needed.

I noticed that this happens to all variables that are modified in any way after an API call is made

Comment: This ought to work in all rendermodes so I think there is something we're not seeing. Create a [mre]. Stub that GetRobotAvatarDetails with an async dummy with Task.Delay()

Comment: So I set up a new project from start but this time instead of using the new project UI i ran the following from the command prompt: 
dotnet new blazor

doing so the api calls work as they should and so does the stream rendering feature

WIll try to see what is the differntce between the 2 project set ups